# Gulp SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, gulp

I just made an script to compile our scss when we save the file with gulp but I execute "**gulp sass**" I receive the next error:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () => {
                                  ^

 

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at requireOrImport (C:\Users\smartinc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js:19:11)
    at execute (C:\Users\smartinc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js:37:3)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\smartinc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js:211:24)
```

This is the code:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

//  Creates the task that will compile our scss
gulp.task('sass', () => {
    // TODO: Must be a way to call a variable with scss route
    return gulp.src('./cartridges/peru/cartridge/client/default/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./cartridges/peru/cartridge/static/default/css'));
});
```

The thing is that it works just fine in my computer but it doesnt work in my partner's computer.
I have no clue of what could be happening.

Any help?

Comment: What versions of Node are you both using?

Comment: We're both using the same version: v10.23.1

Comment: In the top example, you have `function () {` and in the bottom example you have `() => {`. Does that mean the code you ran is not the code you've shared? The `^` also appears to point to the character after the `{` - is it possible you have a weird whitespace character there?

Comment: Sorry! that error was old because we tried with "function ()" instead of " () = >"  we're desperated :D

Comment: Please edit the question and show the actual error message that comes from the code at the bottom, since the error message at the top shows different code.

Comment: I already did it

Comment: what gulp version you are using?